# Why form.exe freezes after clicking button 3 times?

Tags: c#

I launch the C# Form (Via EXE file) on the form I have a button which executes a URL with perimeters (without opening a browser) if the button is clicked more than 3 times (can be at any time) it just completely freezes the program

How can I stop this from happening?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "apiID=2794187564564";

            // Prepare web request...
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                "http://fms.psrpc.co.uk/apistate2.php?" + postData);

            // Send the data.
            myRequest.GetResponse();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a Java programmer and I'm confused: what does this question have to do with Java programming? Why tag it a Java question and attract Java coders if it is not relevant?

Comment: I've removed the Java tag, but in the future, please avoid using irrelevant question tags as they can invite down-votes and they don't help you get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to call `Dispose` on all `IDisposable` types. Although it is not clearly visible here, this applies also to the result of `GetResponse`.

```
// Send the data
myRequest.GetResponse().Dispose();
```

Also note that you should put it inside try-catch-finally because `GetResponse` throws an exception when that http server returns something different than 2xx OK return codes.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to comment back, this worked perfectly thank you